# how to have renderdocui.exe run GTAVLauncher.exe while script hook v dll is in the game directory?

Tags: windows, windows-10, process, port

I get this error when I am starting the GTAV game using RenderDoc (v 0.27) and I have Script HooK V dll in the GTAV game directory (which is for game modding). I get this error: 
 win32_network.cpp( 344) - Warning - Failed to connect to localhost:38921

Seems both Script Hook V and RenderDoc are trying to access the same port and race condition happens. How can I resolve this problem?

Latest version of RenderDoc (v 0.33) doesn't have this problem. 
Latest version of RenderDoc: 
The version of RenderDoc I am using:

When I use Script Hook V separately (meaning I start the GTAV game by clicking on GTAVLauncher.exe not from renderdocui), this is the log I receive:

```
// GTA V SCRIPT HOOK (build Dec 15 2016, v1.0.944.2)
//     (C) Alexander Blade 2015-2016
[18:36:37] INIT: Started
[18:36:37] INIT: Success, game version is VER_1_0_944_2_NOSTEAM
[18:36:37] INIT: Registering script 'NativeTrainer.asi' (0x00007FF9AFD7A3C0)
[18:36:38] INIT: Registering script 'Nice Fly.asi' (0x00007FF9AFA42700)
[18:37:39] INIT: Pool 1 extended
[18:37:39] INIT: Pool 2 extended
[18:37:39] INIT: Pool 3 extended
[18:37:39] INIT: Pool 4 extended
[18:37:44] INIT: GtaThread collection size 188
[18:37:44] INIT: wnd proc 0x00000000FFFF09C3
[18:37:44] INIT: IDXGISwapChain 0x00007FF985C5EB48 (0x00007FF985AE1950)
[18:37:44] INIT: IDXGISwapChain set
[18:37:44] INIT: DX init started
```

And I see the Native Trainer UI like below by pressing F4 in the game:

[image]

And here's what the ports look like using TCPView:

[image]

These are the files I have in GTAV game directory in order to use modding:

[image]

Also these are the ports used by GTAV when running it without script hook v files in the game directory and by clicking on GTAVLauncher.exe (not with the use of renderdocui.exe):

[image]

And when I start the game using renderdocui capture utility I get this log:

```
RENDERDOC:  [19:11:10]             core.cpp( 242) - Log     - RenderDoc v0.27 x64 (NO_GIT_COMMIT_HASH_DEFINED) loaded in replay application
RENDERDOC:  [19:11:55]    win32_process.cpp( 307) - Log     - Injecting renderdoc into process 10244
RENDERDOC:  [19:11:56]    remote_access.cpp( 389) - Log     - Got remote handshake: GTAVLauncher () [10244]
RENDERDOC:  [19:12:00]    remote_access.cpp( 558) - Log     - Got a new child process: 11544 38921
RENDERDOC:  [19:12:07]    remote_access.cpp( 558) - Log     - Got a new child process: 2568 38923
RENDERDOC:  [19:12:17]    remote_access.cpp( 558) - Log     - Got a new child process: 256 38923
```

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: If the current version of `RenderDoc` doesn't cause the crash why are you using the previous version of `RenderDoc `?

Comment: I am using "playing for data" version of renderdoc. It has numerous changes in the code and the used libraries that could not be resolved by git. Google "playing for data" with quotes and you will see the code in bitbucket

Comment: @MonaJalal did you ever have luck with play for data Renderdoc on GTAV?