# Turning off Hyperthreading in Windows 10 in Gigabyte P57 Laptop

Tags: windows, windows-10, bios, uefi, hyper-threading

I don't see an option for hyperthreading or HT in my bios even though I know hyperthreading is enabled. How can I disable it? Here's the screenshots from all the BIOS tabs:
*What is the solution, if the current gaming laptop doesn't provide the option to disable the HT? 
[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]
[image]

[image]

Comment: You can't;  Your firmware **must** offer the option into order to disable it.  What pratical problem are you trying to solve by disabling Hyperthreading.  Perhaps we can solve your actual problem?

Comment: Someone wrote and others confirmed disabling hypertheading would solved GTA5.exe crashing problem https://superuser.com/questions/1183869/how-to-have-renderdocui-exe-run-gtavlauncher-exe-while-script-hook-v-dll-is-in-t

Comment: Try the onboard device config under Advanced

Comment: I tried and there is a screenshot if it. Nothing there

Comment: What's the exact error when it's crashing? You can find this by looking in event viewer and see the error code when the .exe crashed. I had the same issue but mine crashed with a 0x5c or 0xc5. I can't remember. The problem ended up being my PCIe slot.

Comment: Check with your manufacturer for a firmware (BIOS) update for your motherboard which might add support or even fix the issue without needing to disable hyperthreading. Likewise check for updated drivers for your graphics and other key components. I have a similar processor but do not see crashes even though hyperthreading is enabled.

Comment: @drzoo if you talk about gta5 it gives me 0xc0000005 error which is equivalent to access violation. When this happens the computer slows down significantly and debugging it with visual studio doesn't really provide further information. The game screen also becomes black

Comment: "The most typical causes for the ‘0xC0000005: Access Violation’ error are: corrupt registry, malware, faulty RAM or device driver, incorrectly written, installed or updated software or even Windows security features." http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/answers/id-2941079/games-applications-ctd-error-code-0xc0000005-memory-access-violation.html While reinstalling Windows is a bit extreme, it might help.

Comment: Antivirus programs also seem to be an affecting factor in this issue. I cannot find anything suggesting hyperthreading is the problem.

Comment: Have you disabled or removed all mods or injected DLLs from your earlier question about GTA V and done a **completely** clean install? https://superuser.com/questions/1183869/how-to-have-renderdocui-exe-run-gtavlauncher-exe-while-script-hook-v-dll-is-in-t

Comment: When I remove dinput8.dll or dsound.dll the game works fine.